# Pandas Append Sum of Multy DataFrames Separately to Target DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I need to get sum of couple DataFrames and append each result to a target DataFrames(`df_sum`)

```
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Source', 'Column2_SUM', 'Column3_SUM'])
```

I have 4 dataframe as

```
import pandas as pd

data_A = {'Column1': ['2023-06-16','2023-08-24','2023-04-24'],
          'Column2': [4, 5, 6],
          'Column3': [7, 8, 9]}

data_B = {'Column1': ['2023-07-19','2023-08-24','2023-03-18'],
          'Column2': [4, 96, 6],
          'Column3': [12, 8, 9]}

data_C = {'Column1': ['2023-06-22','2023-04-20','2023-09-12'],
          'Column2': [4, 88, 6],
          'Column3': [7, 8, 12]}

data_D = {'Column1': ['2023-08-27','2023-11-24','2023-04-08'],
          'Column2': [4, 32, 6],
          'Column3': [66, 8, 80]}


df_A = pd.DataFrame(data_A)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data_B)
df_C = pd.DataFrame(data_C)
df_D = pd.DataFrame(data_D)
```

now what I need is to get something like, lo be loaded up to `df_sum`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary for specify names of DataFrames, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `sum`, add [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column `SOURCE`:

```
d = {'df_A':df_A, 'df_B':df_B, 'df_C':df_C, 'df_D':df_D}

df = (pd.concat(d)
        .groupby(level=0)[['Column2','Column3']].sum()
        .add_suffix('_SUM')
        .rename_axis('SOURCE')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  SOURCE  Column2_SUM  Column3_SUM
0   df_A           15           24
1   df_B          106           29
2   df_C           98           27
3   df_D           42          154
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, just one extra question, while waiting to accept your answer as correct solution! how I can handle havinf a `NAN` data inside one of columns.? I mean I am not sure I may get some NA data when creating dynamic DataFrames?

Comment: @Behseini - pandas by default omit `NaN`s, test `data_A = {'Column1': ['2023-06-16','2023-08-24','2023-04-24'],
          'Column2': [np.nan, np.nan, 6],
          'Column3': [7, 8, 9]}`